# How to scale to fit image inside svg

Tags: svg, image-resizing

I'm trying to modify a svg to make the image it holds take the full width and height of the svg. How can I do that?

I'm trying to modify width and height to 100%, x, y to "0" and set this svg property preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet".

This is the initial svg :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="1512" height="1063" viewBox="0 0 1512 1063" xml:space="preserve">
    <desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.6.7</desc>
    <defs></defs>
    <g transform="translate(776.8 529.9) scale(1.01 0.95)">
        <image id="1554312687213" xlink:href="https://lobservateur-avesnois.easypubphr.fr/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2018/11/restaurantmodel.png" x="-730.5" y="-782" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: none; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="1461" height="1564" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
    </g>
    <g id="1554312687241" transform="translate(781 762.29)">
        <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="43" font-style="normal" font-weight="bold" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">
            <tspan x="-164" y="13.54" fill="#ffffff">Votre entreprise</tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
    <g id="1554312687289" transform="translate(779 847.3)">
        <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="20" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">
            <tspan x="-68.31" y="6.3" fill="#ffffff">Votre adresse </tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
    <g id="1554312687296" transform="translate(776 811.17)">
        <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="18" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">
            <tspan x="-68.83" y="5.67" fill="#ffffff">Votre telephone</tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10vw 30vw;
}

svg {
  border: 5px solid;
}
```

```html
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?--><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="219" height="302" viewBox="0 0 1512 1063" xml:space="preserve"><desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.6.7</desc><defs></defs><g transform="translate(776.8 529.9) scale(1.01 0.95)"><image id="1554312687213" xlink:href="https://lobservateur-avesnois.easypubphr.fr/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2018/11/restaurantmodel.png" x="-730.5" y="-782" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: none; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="1461" height="1564" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image></g> <g id="1554312687241" transform="translate(781 762.29)">  <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="43" font-style="normal" font-weight="bold" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">   <tspan x="-164" y="13.54" fill="#ffffff">Votre entreprise</tspan>  </text> </g> <g id="1554312687289" transform="translate(779 847.3)">  <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="20" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">   <tspan x="-68.31" y="6.3" fill="#ffffff">Votre adresse </tspan>  </text> </g> <g id="1554312687296" transform="translate(776 811.17)">  <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="18" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">   <tspan x="-68.83" y="5.67" fill="#ffffff">Votre telephone</tspan>  </text> </g></svg>
```

What I've been trying to do :

```css
body {
  padding: 10vw 30vw;
}

svg {
  border: 5px solid;
}
```

```html
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?--><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="219" height="302" viewBox="0 0 1512 1063" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"><g transform="translate(776.8 529.9) scale(1.01 0.95)"><image id="1554312687213" xlink:href="https://lobservateur-avesnois.easypubphr.fr/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2018/11/restaurantmodel.png" x="0" y="0" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: none; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image></g> <g id="1554312687241" transform="translate(781 762.29)">  <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="43" font-style="normal" font-weight="bold" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">   <tspan x="-164" y="13.54" fill="#ffffff">Votre entreprise</tspan>  </text> </g> <g id="1554312687289" transform="translate(779 847.3)">  <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="20" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">   <tspan x="-68.31" y="6.3" fill="#ffffff">Votre adresse </tspan>  </text> </g> <g id="1554312687296" transform="translate(776 811.17)">  <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="18" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">   <tspan x="-68.83" y="5.67" fill="#ffffff">Votre telephone</tspan>  </text> </g></svg>
```

I expect this result :

```css
body {
  padding: 10vw 30vw;
}

svg {
  border: 5px solid;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 579 375" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
  
  <image xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9674/photo-1501366062246-723b4d3e4eb6.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
  
</svg>
```

But if i just change image url of expect svg, result is different of what i expect i don't understand why.

```css
body {
  padding: 10vw 30vw;
}

svg {
  border: 5px solid;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 579 375" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
  
  <image xlink:href="https://lobservateur-avesnois.easypubphr.fr/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2018/11/restaurantmodel.png" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
  
</svg>
```

The final objective is to download the svg in png. The code to transform to png is finished however because of this svg problem, the final image is not good.

Comment: You are required to post your markup and code here, not any third party site. [mcve]

Comment: Do you expect us to study the three CodePen examples and spot the differences in the SVG?

Comment: I have add code in stackoverflow snippet sorry for that. The only difference is the image in the svg. I added some explanations to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the `viewBox` attribute.  The one you currently have is way too big.  Your important content occupies a small portion in the middle of that area.

Your current `viewBox` is:

```
viewBox="0 0 1512 1063"
```

A better `viewBox` that matches the non-transparent part of your background image is:

```
viewBox="472 16 616 960"
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10vw 30vw;
}

svg {
  border: 5px solid;
}
```

```html
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?-->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="219" height="302" viewBox="472 16 616 960" xml:space="preserve">
  <desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.6.7</desc>
  <defs></defs>
  <g transform="translate(776.8 529.9) scale(1.01 0.95)">
    <image id="1554312687213" xlink:href="https://lobservateur-avesnois.easypubphr.fr/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2018/11/restaurantmodel.png" x="-730.5" y="-782" width="1461" height="1564" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
  </g>
  <g id="1554312687241" transform="translate(781 762.29)">
    <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="43" font-style="normal" font-weight="bold" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">
      <tspan x="-164" y="13.54" fill="#ffffff">Votre entreprise</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="1554312687289" transform="translate(779 847.3)">
    <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="20" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">
      <tspan x="-68.31" y="6.3" fill="#ffffff">Votre adresse </tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="1554312687296" transform="translate(776 811.17)">
    <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="18" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">
      <tspan x="-68.83" y="5.67" fill="#ffffff">Votre telephone</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

However in this example it still does not fit exactly.  That is because your SVG dimensions (219 x 302) have a different aspect ratio to the image/viewBox (616x960).

You can fix that in various ways:

1. You could stretch the viewBox area, to fit the wider SVG dimensions, by adding `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to the SVG.

```css
body {
  padding: 10vw 30vw;
}

svg {
  border: 5px solid;
}
```

```html
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?-->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="219" height="302" viewBox="472 16 616 960" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.6.7</desc>
  <defs></defs>
  <g transform="translate(776.8 529.9) scale(1.01 0.95)">
    <image id="1554312687213" xlink:href="https://lobservateur-avesnois.easypubphr.fr/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2018/11/restaurantmodel.png" x="-730.5" y="-782" width="1461" height="1564" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
  </g>
  <g id="1554312687241" transform="translate(781 762.29)">
    <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="43" font-style="normal" font-weight="bold" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">
      <tspan x="-164" y="13.54" fill="#ffffff">Votre entreprise</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="1554312687289" transform="translate(779 847.3)">
    <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="20" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">
      <tspan x="-68.31" y="6.3" fill="#ffffff">Votre adresse </tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="1554312687296" transform="translate(776 811.17)">
    <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="18" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">
      <tspan x="-68.83" y="5.67" fill="#ffffff">Votre telephone</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

2. You could arrange for the viewBox area to be enlarged to fit the wider SVG dimensions (equivalent to HTML's `background-size: cover`), by adding `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"` to the SVG.

```css
body {
  padding: 10vw 30vw;
}

svg {
  border: 5px solid;
}
```

```html
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?-->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="219" height="302" viewBox="472 16 616 960" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
  <desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.6.7</desc>
  <defs></defs>
  <g transform="translate(776.8 529.9) scale(1.01 0.95)">
    <image id="1554312687213" xlink:href="https://lobservateur-avesnois.easypubphr.fr/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2018/11/restaurantmodel.png" x="-730.5" y="-782" width="1461" height="1564" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
  </g>
  <g id="1554312687241" transform="translate(781 762.29)">
    <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="43" font-style="normal" font-weight="bold" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">
      <tspan x="-164" y="13.54" fill="#ffffff">Votre entreprise</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="1554312687289" transform="translate(779 847.3)">
    <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="20" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">
      <tspan x="-68.31" y="6.3" fill="#ffffff">Votre adresse </tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="1554312687296" transform="translate(776 811.17)">
    <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="18" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">
      <tspan x="-68.83" y="5.67" fill="#ffffff">Votre telephone</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

3. You could make the SVG narrower by reducing the `width` attribute.  A more correct value would be:

   ```
   302 * (616/960) ~= 194
   ```

```css
body {
  padding: 10vw 30vw;
}

svg {
  border: 5px solid;
}
```

```html
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?-->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="194" height="302" viewBox="472 16 616 960">
  <desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.6.7</desc>
  <defs></defs>
  <g transform="translate(776.8 529.9) scale(1.01 0.95)">
    <image id="1554312687213" xlink:href="https://lobservateur-avesnois.easypubphr.fr/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2018/11/restaurantmodel.png" x="-730.5" y="-782" width="1461" height="1564" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
  </g>
  <g id="1554312687241" transform="translate(781 762.29)">
    <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="43" font-style="normal" font-weight="bold" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">
      <tspan x="-164" y="13.54" fill="#ffffff">Votre entreprise</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="1554312687289" transform="translate(779 847.3)">
    <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="20" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">
      <tspan x="-68.31" y="6.3" fill="#ffffff">Votre adresse </tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="1554312687296" transform="translate(776 811.17)">
    <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="18" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">
      <tspan x="-68.83" y="5.67" fill="#ffffff">Votre telephone</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that the image has a wide transparent border. You either need to use a Photoshop like software to cut off that border or you can do it like this:

```css
body {
  padding: 10vw 30vw;
}

svg {
  border: 5px solid;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-304 -506 608 1005" >
    <g id="theg">
      <image id="1554312687213" xlink:href="https://lobservateur-avesnois.easypubphr.fr/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2018/11/restaurantmodel.png" x="-733" y="-750" width="1461" height="1564"></image>
</g>
    <g id="theText" text-anchor="middle" fill="#ffffff">
        <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="43" font-style="normal" font-weight="bold" >Votre entreprise</text>
      <text font-family="ABeeZee" y="30" font-size="20" >Votre adresse</text>
      <text font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="18" y="60" >Votre telephone</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```